# ios5 and ios6 Rotation with diffrence allow rotation

Tags: objective-c, rotation

Using UINavigationController,
When from the view allows all directions to return to the landscape rotatable,
the view is bad access or force view to portrait..

How to return from the all rotatebleview to only rotateble landscape view in UINavigationController...